# Clicking on dynamic edittext,setting contact number for particular edittext on activity result in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to set contact number in edit text when clicking on dynamic edit text. I'm getting switch case error.

This is dynamic edit text where I'm implementing onclickListener goes to contact intent.

```
if ((list.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXX"))) {
                    editText[editCounter].setOnClickListener(this);

                    editText[editCounter].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
                        }
                    });
```

//this is onactivty result code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        switch (requestCode) {  
        case PICK_CONTACT:

            Cursor cursor = null;  
            String phoneNumber = "";
            List<String> allNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
            int phoneIdx = 0;
            try {  
                Uri result = data.getData();  
                String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);  
                phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                        phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                        allNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                } else {
                    //no results actions
                }  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
               //error actions
            } finally {  
                if (cursor != null) {  
                    cursor.close();

                }


                final CharSequence[] items = allNumbers.toArray(new String[allNumbers.size()]);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomFormActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose a number");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        String selectedNumber = items[item].toString();
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber.replace("-", "");




                       /* for (ControlListObject list : controlArray) {

                             if((list.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXX")))
                                    {
                        editText[editCounter].setText(selectedNumber);}
                        }*/
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                if(allNumbers.size() >= 1) {
                    alert.show();
                } else {
                    String selectedNumber = phoneNumber.toString();
                    selectedNumber = selectedNumber.replace("-", "");

                   // editText.setText(selectedNumber);

                    for (ControlListObject list : controlArray) {


                         if((list.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXX")))
                                {


                   editText[editCounter].setText(selectedNumber);


                                }}
                }
                        // }




                if (phoneNumber.length() == 0) {  
                    //no numbers found actions  
                }  
            }  
            break;  
        }  
    } else {
       //activity result error actions
    }  
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to provide the specific errors you are getting.

Comment: case PICK_CONTACT: red mark -- case expressions must be constant expressions

Comment: So, it is telling you that PICK_CONTACT is not a constant, rather it is a variable or similar...  You need to put a definable-at-compile-time value in for the case statements...

Comment: Can you please tel me whats is wrong -- this is how i declare  contact --
private static int PICK_CONTACT = 1; my mind is not at all working

Comment: Ross , please help me

Comment: Thank you Anyways .. It  works with "if else"  block rather than switch.